# MAC OS in Windows machine to run FCP

Tags: macos, windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, mac

I have to run **final cut pro** in my windows system..

Is there possible to run MAC OS on windows machine?
I have an idea to create virtual drive. but it will slow down the system. 
any other options? and tell me which version is suitable for.

Comment: how about virtual box? with good settings it should do

Comment: thanks Petr Marek.. will u please explain more... Im new to mac. tel about mac versions that suit.

Comment: hey.. y down votes?? Stack Overflow is a place to share ideas..hmm. anyway thanks for your response. :-)

Comment: ganesh check out http://www.virtualbox.org/ and grab a macos iso somewhere. Also note that legally, macos can only be run on apple hardware